# How do I get social bookmarking with my own icons?

Tags: html, css, twitter, icons, social-networking

You can see what I am talking about at www.ethoma.com/wd/. Basically, as you can see on the right, I have a bunch of my own icons that I custom formatted to fit my site nicely. Because they are my own icon, all they are right now are little hyperlinks. I was wondering if I could also get a "tweet" button or a twitter button that automatically hit follow for the user, and didn't just simply bring him to my profile. I know I can do this, but when I do, I end up with the very misfitting icon that Twitter gives you.

My question is, is there a way to get these like buttons and social bookmarking buttons without the stock icon facebook gives you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make social media buttons available to your users you might want to check out AddThis. They provive a rich API for many different social media sites including facebook twitter google plus etc.

I know you can use your own icons and customize a whole bunch of things (which are all well documented on their website) but I don't know if you can have your own like button. But if they can do it/provide the option you can too, somehow.

http://www.addthis.com/help/custom-buttons#different-image